# I want to understand AUTO_INCREMENT value in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
ALTER TABLE [table name] AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

SET @COUNT = 0;

UPDATE [table name] SET [AUTO_INCREMENT colon name ] = @COUNT:=@COUNT+1;
```

When I use this `id`, it was indexed from 1, but when i add new row to the table, `id` was 5. I know, when I use the above commend `id` will be indexed well, but I wonder why after use that next new row `id` was 5.
Can anyone explain why this happened?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Why does it matter? The purpose of auto increment is to generate unique values, not to generate a sequence of values.